# Obsfucate a 5 digit number

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash

I wish to obfuscate a 5 digit number

Properties of the obfuscated number that I care about:

- it's impossible (or as a fall back, extremely unlikely) to collide with other obfuscated numbers
- it's also a 5 digit number (no alpha characters please)
- it's not easily determinable by a regular human without computational assistance (e.g. it's not something obvious like "multiply by 2 and subtract 5"
- it's an algorithm ... as opposed to storing a look up table of all possible 5 digit numbers to their corresponding hash or some other "brute force" technique

Properties of the obfuscated number that I don't care about:

- whether it's repeatable or not i.e. if "12345" always results in "73624", I okay
- whether it's cryptographically secure or not

Thus far I haven't found anything that fits my requirements... but am hoping this is due to poor memory, incomplete education or dubious lifestyle choices rather than no "nice" solution being present.

An example that can be easily translated into C# would be a bonus.

**Update:**

I'm investigating using the idea of doing a simple bit mapping for the moment.

```
   static List<int> bitMapping = new List<int>() { 8, 6, 9, 3, 7, 5, ... etc... };

    private static int Obfuscate(int number)
    {
        var bits = new bool[bitMapping.Count];
        foreach (var ordinal in bitMapping)
        {
            var mask = (int)Math.Pow(2, ordinal);
            var bit = (mask & number) == mask;
            var mappedOrdinal = bitMapping[ordinal];
            bits[mappedOrdinal] = bit;
        }

        var obfuscatedNumber = 0;
        for (var ordinal = 0; ordinal < bits.Length; ordinal++)
        {
            if (bits[ordinal])
            {
                obfuscatedNumber += (int)Math.Pow(2, ordinal);
            }
        }
        return obfuscatedNumber;
```

It seems to meet most of my requirements thus far.

Comment: By definition, a hash is repeatable.  If you don't care about that property, why don't you just replace the number with a pseudo-randomly generated number?

Comment: If you don't care of consistency "I don't care about: whether it's repeatable" then return random value

Comment: Where will it be stored? I ask because multiplying by two and subtracting 5 is not easily decrypted by a user just looking at the numerical value.. it could be anything originally..

Comment: @paddy Happy with psuedo random... just need the psuedo random numbers not to collide

Comment: @lzcd: create an array of 100k integers and pick numbers from it. After you picked - remove it from the array

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think it's a good fit for SO in that it's too subjective.  There isn't a single "right" answer to this question.

Comment: You want to ensure that two 5-digit random numbers won't be the same?!  You can't, but it is unlikely.  I think it's time that you explained WHAT this is for and HOW you intend to use it.

Comment: @templatetypedef If multiple solutions are provided which fit the cirteria stated then I'll happily concede the question is a bad fit... but thus far a single solution, let alone multiple ones, has yet to be provided.

Comment: One way: Add an offset to each digit, with wrap-around so that they remain digits - one fixed offset per position, so, say, 3, 5, 7, 4, and 8. Kind of like a combination lock to a safe. To decrypt, subtract the values.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I like the sound of that and would recommend offering it as an answer.

Comment: @paddy No fussed if it's random or not. (Randomly generated numbers however do tend to present the need to store them so that one can avoid collisions... which is one aspect I'm hoping to avoid for numerous reasons). The main thing I'm interested in is avoiding an obvious correlation between the source and obfuscation number.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Maybe I am missing something here, but isn't that the same as just adding 35748 to the number?

Comment: The identify function handles all of your requirements, with the advantage that if the user starts making operations to guess the actual number, they will never find it (since they already have the actual number).

Comment: i guess by repeatable he means unique, ie there could be multiple representations that point back to the same input.  With both representations the same size clearly the transformation must be unique so that's an irrelevant non-requirement.

Comment: I just noticed I wrote "identify function", I actually meant the dummy "identity function". @george is that comment towards my other comment ? I don't see how it makes sense, supposing you understood I meant "identity function", and not something else.

Comment: @Gray: You're not missing anything.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Ha, Ok. I just never really thought about it like how you phrased it I guess. And the OP suggesting you post it as an answer when there was one like that convinced me that I must be missing something.

Comment: [Other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8554286/1009831) has similar (though a little bit stricter) requirements.

Answer (score 2):

That might be too simple for your needs, but something that works and might not be as obvious as an addition is the XOR operation :

```
12345 ^ 65535 = 53190
53190 ^ 65535 = 12345
```

As noted in comments it is important that the second operand is of the form (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) to avoid collisions (so that every bit in the original number is inverted). It also needs to be long enough that its number of bits is greater or equal than the first operand.

You might also have to pad-left with 0's to make the result a 5-digit number.

Comment: Someone smarter than me might be able to say why, but I *suspect* there would be collisions with this because XOR is commutative. Maybe if you keep the key constant, then it wont be an issue? This is just speculation, as I haven't researched it enough to dispute your answer.

Comment: If you choose the second constant so that it is a power of 2 minus 1 (i.e., all 1's in binary), then there will be no collisions.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. What if you do a series of XORs and additions? Would that make for a legitimate 1:1 substitution?

Comment: It would, because the composition of 2 [bijections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective#Composition) is a bijection.

Comment: I feel like that would make for a pretty difficult to de-obfuscate number then. Not that it would be impossible to crack, but it would surely have taken me some time to figure it out, ha!

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be too bad. You could throw in some bit rotations/permutations as well. Though people will argue that [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) isn't a very good strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want collisions then multiplication/division are out. In which case then I would

1. Add a 5 digit seed value to your number, if it overflows into six digits discard the sixth.
2. Reorder the digits in some consistent way.

E.g.

12345 + 97531 = 109876 or 09876 after discard overflow 
Reorder to 68097

Comment: How "If you don't want collisions" correlates with "Reorder the digits in some way."?

Comment: It doesn't. The collisions would be inherent from any multiplication or division where you are ignoring overflow or underflow. i.e. 00000*5 =0, 2000*5 = 100000 which rounds to 00000, and 00020/5 = 00004, 00021/5 = 00004.2 which rounds to 00004.