# How should I encode two integers into lowercase alphanumeric characters?

Tags: math, hash, encoding, character-encoding

I have two integers from 0 to infinity (in practice probably less than 1 million, but don't want to have any limitation). I want to encode the two integers into a lowercase alphanumeric string (which may contain a dash, but shouldn't be just numbers). Also I want the strings to be somewhat random (i.e. don't want to always prefix every int with "a" for example). The most important requirement is that I need to be able to easily decode this alphanumeric string.

I would normally just use md5 hashing but it doesn't work for this case as I can't go back from md5 to the original integers. I also considered Base64 but it doesn't work because strings may include uppercase.

Is there a known hashing algorithm that satisfies these requirements?

Comment: What about Base-32?

Comment: It wouldn't be a hashing algorithm if it's reversable, just an encoding algorithm, to be pedantic.

Comment: When you say "somewhat random," what do you mean? Random as in unpredictable or random as in highly distributed for sequential values?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554286/obfuscating-an-id for ideas for obfuscating your value, then after it's obfuscated, you can just encode it with something simple like Base-32.

Comment: Base-32 looks like what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you're just looking to change the integer's base

Instead of base64 you can use base 16 (aka hexadecimal):

```
>>> hex(1234)[2:]
'4d2'
>>> int('4d2', 16)
1234
```

or base32:

```
>>> b32_encode(1234)
b'atja===='
>>> b32_decode(b'atja====')
1234
```

## If you're looking to obscure the integer

The simplest method is to multiple the integer by some number and then xor with some greater, randomized key:

```
>>> key = 0xFa907fA06 # The result of punching my keyboard.
>>> number = 15485863
>>> obscured = (1234 * number) ^ key
50902290680
>>> hex(obscured)
'bda0350f8'
>>> (50902290680 ^ key) / number
1234
```

Wanting more robust obfuscation than that requires a tad bit more research, in which case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554286/obfuscating-an-id) similar question may be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I found a library that does just what I need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids